# Reactjs serever side stylesheet not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Reactjs server side. when I implemented style.css file in my project.
but when I run that project then It display error :

[image: display this error.]

So,how can I resolve this. I also try fs: empty in my code then output like this.

[image: When add fs empty in code]

So,that didn't work for me.

here, my server.js code

```js
require('babel-register')({presets: ['react']});
var express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('app'));

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var Home = require('./app/components/index.js');
var AboutUs = require('./app/components/about.jsx');
var Gallery = require('./app/components/gallery.jsx');
var NotFound = require('./app/components/not_found.jsx');



app.get('/', function(request, response){
  var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Home));
  response.send(html);
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response){
  var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Home));
  response.send(html);
});

app.get('/about', function(request, response){
  var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(AboutUs));
  response.send(html);
});

app.get('/gallery', function(request, response){
  var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Gallery));
  response.send(html);
});



var port =2000; //process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening application at : http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Please, help me.

Comment: looks like some dependencies are missing from your project. Try making an update with your package manager (npm/yarn)

Comment: have you tried requiring fs ? `const fs = require('fs');`

Comment: yes, I tried same. I update npm install @chris and I also tried add const fs= require('fs') by using that error should gone and dispaly warning but project should not run.. Robert

Comment: Please try to include error messages as text rather than screenshots in the future - it's easier for people to read/copy, and it's more considerate of those who are using screen readers.

Comment: Can you show us the `server.js` file ?

Comment: I add server.js code please check it.